# Why it took so long to download sbt dependencies when I create a scala project in intellij idea?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to scala, when I create a scala project in intellij it took really so long to download all the jar files. I have installed the scala plugin for idea IDE. Could anyone please tell me what should I do to get on the right track? Thanks very much.
[image]

Comment: How long does an sbt ~package take you outside of intellij?

Comment: Does this question have an answer, or is it just a complaint?

Comment: It's true - it is taking a surprisingly long time.  My guess (not knowing anything) is that the files are large, or that the server is slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the screenshot it try to download the source files of one of of the dependencies. That mean it will try to download not only the compiled jars, but also it's source and docs.
only after downloading all of them, the project will be ready.
Disable to downloading of the sources and docs, and it will be much faster. How to disable it depends on how you create the project.  (eg if you create sbt project, make sure to uncheck the "download sources and docs" in the creation/import wizard)

Answer (score 9):

Since the *scala* language is really a library on top of the JVM, creating a *scala* project for the first time requires the download of the specified scala version from a maven repository (*usually this is at least the compiler and library, which for 2.10 comes to ~20MB*). This will happen the first time, even if you've installed that same version of scala on your machine outside of `sbt`.

Once you go through this the first time, though, the next project you create--whether via `sbt` on the command line or via an IntelliJ `sbt` project--will pull these dependencies from your local `ivy` cache instead.

However, should you change the language version in your project, it will once again have to download the full language dependencies for that version.